# How to make JTextField allow only number

Tags: java, jtextfield

I want to do calc with java. I am using Netbeans IDE. I want to make my JTextField allow only double numbers. What is the shortcut code to do this?

Comment: begging for code with no research or effort is off-topic

Comment: write a validation method on focus of the text field

Comment: I search all things about it and try all codes but they aren't execute.

Answer (score 0):

Like everybody else whose asked to question, try using a

- [JSpinner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)
- [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)
- [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Comment: I solve this problem with using JFormattedTextField with changing formatterFactory property.